# How to handle a long if statement to read input that has many common parts?

Tags: java, refactoring

I am writing a simple Java program that interacts a lot with the user (through command line).

Consider that there is a unique code in order to do each possible action. However, each action requires further input. The problem is that many different actions require similar input. Therefore, I end up with something like this:

```
int input = scanner.nextInt();
String commonInputA, commonInputB, commonInputC, commonInputD;
if (input == 1) {
    //receive required input for action 1
    commonInputA = scanner.next();
    commonInputB = scanner.next();
} else if (input == 2) {
    //receive required input for action 2
    commonInputB = scanner.next();
    commonInputD = scanner.next();
} else if (input == 3) {
    //receive required input for action 3
    commonInputA = scanner.next();
    commonInputC = scanner.next();
} else if (input == 4) {
    //receive required input for action 4
    commonInputA = scanner.next();
    commonInputB = scanner.next();
    commonInputC = scanner.next();
    commonInputD = scanner.next();
} else if (input == 5) {
    //no extra input required to perform action 5
}
```

Of course, those commonInputs are used as constructor parameters to initialise objects. Is there a way to write the above input receiver in a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1):

One of the way to accept common input.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimpleClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner      = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[][] map          = {{0, 1}, {1, 3}, {0, 2}, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {}};
        int input            = scanner.nextInt();
        String[] commonInput = readCommonInput(input, map, scanner);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(commonInput));

        //Calling your constructor
        //commonInputA is stored at commonInput[0]
        //commonInputB is stored at commonInput[1]
        //commonInputC is stored at commonInput[2]
        //commonInputD is stored at commonInput[3]
        //CommonInputProcessor p = new CommonInputProcessor(commonInput[0], commonInput[1], commonInput[2], commonInput[3]);
    }

    public static String[] readCommonInput(int input, int[][] map, Scanner scanner)
    {
        String[] commonInput = new String[4];

        for(int i : map[input - 1])
        {
            commonInput[i] = scanner.next();
        }

        return commonInput;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below

```
int input = scanner.nextInt();
String commonInputA, commonInputB, commonInputC, commonInputD;

if(input!=2)
commonInputA = scanner.next();
if(input!=3)
commonInputB = scanner.next();
if(input!=1&&input!=2) 
commonInputC = scanner.next();
 

if (input == 1) {
//perform input 1 action
}
else if (input == 2) {
    commonInputD = scanner.next();
} else if (input == 3) {
//perform input 3 action

} else if (input == 4) {
    commonInputD = scanner.next();
}
```